# Redis Cluster Master Failover Scenario

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

In a 6 nodes Redis Cluster, with 3 master nodes and 3 slave nodes, if let's say a master will go down, the according slave will be promoted. When the old master comes back live will be a slave.

Is it possible to force it somehow from the redis config or otherwise, so that when it comes back live, the old master will be promoted as a master as it was at the beginning?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the old master comes up with property:

```
slaveof no one
```

It will join the cluster as a master, but I don't think you would like to do it.
The 'old master' does not have the latest data, if you force it to become the master, there will be data loss.